# Windows update download stuck at 99%

Tags: windows, windows-update

**PROBLEM**

Hi, so my windows 10 is downloading an update. Currently it is on 99% of the download and it won't move from there. I runned troubleshooter but it failed to detect any problems, I cleaned temporal files, as suggested in some post, and I have also activated my license, fearing it was not genuine (because someone else installed it for me) but it just won't move!
Any help is really, much appreciated.

**ADITIONAL INFORMATION.**

The reason why I decided to install a new update is because my Windows has presented problems, big problems with default aplications, and small ones too, like changing the backdrop image in presentation mode. For some reason I have also found that Windows update (or 99% of it) installed in my Hard Drive, not in my SSD where the real Windoes currently is...
Also recently my PC ran into automatic recovery after it failed booting during a Windows update, I took the desktop to technical support and they restored it without formating it, they just inserted a USB into my PC that contained Windows, so windows could find there the missing files and repaired itself. I took the liberty to post my Window's specs in case it helps.

*Edition: Windows 10 Pro*

*Version: 1803*

*Operative System version: 17134.472.*

*System tipe: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor*

Thanks.

Comment: When you ran the troubleshooter, did it mention anything in the detailed report?

Comment: No, It just said something like: troubleshooter could not find the problem...
Close troubleshooter and there was another option about sending feedback about the troubleshooter to microsoft or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying the troubleshooter from Microsoft's website:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter

This is significantly more involved than the one that is included with Windows 10. When I had an issue with installing 1809, this tool discovered that the files Windows Update downloaded for installation had gotten corrupted. After it cleaned them out WU redownloaded them and the installation was successful.

Comment: Thanks K.A what about " I have also found that Windows update (or 99% of it) installed in my Hard Drive, not in my SSD where the real Windoes currently is..."
Is that normal?
Also, the Troubleshooter has been running for a long time, but has not found the problem yet...
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry K.A, the troubleshooter could not identify the problem...
But Thanks anyway